# Get time difference between datetime and a constant time variable pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, datetime

I have a DateTime  column "Ended" and want to create a new column if the time is greater than 19:00:00 else 0.
The new column should contain the difference between "Ended" and 19:00:00 in hours...

```
Ended                   New_Ended
2020-10-31 21:06:30     2.1
2020-10-31 20:29:18     1.5
2020-10-01 19:24:42     0.4
2020-10-03 16:24:42     0.0


datetime64[ns]
```

And Similarly if the "Started" is before 08:30 then get time difference between "Started" and 8:30 in terms of hours

```
Open                   New_Open
2020-10-22 7:56:00      0.56
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try

```
# add 19:00:00 to the starts of the days
end_thresh = df['Ended'].dt.floor('D') + pd.Timedelta('19H')

df['New Ended'] = (df['Ended'].sub(end_thresh)   # subtract the threshold
                     .div(pd.Timedelta('1H'))    # divide by 1H
                     .clip(lower=0)              # replace negatives with 0
                  )
```

Output:

```
                Ended  New_Ended
0 2020-10-31 21:06:30   2.108333
1 2020-10-31 20:29:18   1.488333
2 2020-10-01 19:24:42   0.411667
3 2020-10-03 16:24:42   0.000000
```

Same logic with `Open` except that you would swap thresh and the column in subtraction.